# If Y is a subset of X, is always true that then Y inherits (always) a total order from X?

Tags: order-theory, model-theory, order-topology

> If Y is a subset of X, then Y inherits a total order from X. The set Y therefore has an order topology, the induced order topology

What does it mean "inherits" ? Is this a a Kripke [model M construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke_semantics#Model_constructions)?

> Because inhabited sets are the same as nonempty sets in classical logic, it is not possible to produce a model in the classical sense that contains a nonempty set X but does not satisfy "X is inhabited". But it is possible to construct a Kripke model M that satisfies "X is nonempty" without satisfying "X is inhabited".

Is a subset of total order ?

> In mathematics, a linear order, total order, simple order, or (non-strict) ordering is a binary relation on some set  X, which is antisymmetric, transitive, and a connex relation

or is a [cover set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_(topology)) ?

> a cover of a set $X$ is a collection of sets whose union contains $X$ as a subset

i don't understand that word "inherits", for me is cryptic

Comment: I'm baffled as to why this should have anything to do with Kripke models or covers. To inherit just means to get from. It's not being used as a technical math word, it's an ordinary English word. If $X$ is a totally ordered set, any subset $Y\subseteq X$ also has a total order that it gets from $X$, as described in Ross Millikan's answer. That's all that's going on here.

Answer (score 3):

Having a total order on $X$ says that every pair of elements of $X$ are comparable and the order is transitive.  If you extract a subset $Y$, between any two elements you can use the comparison in the total order on $X$.  It will be transitive, so it is a total order on $Y$.  "Inherits" means that given you have a total order on $X$ you also have one on $Y$ that comes from the one on $X$.